# Linux commands - invoke with arguments

Tags: linux, terminal, command, invoke

Is there a way invoking a linux command with an argument?
For example, When invoking "su" a password is requested,
I want to paste a string in the terminal that will call su and fill
the password (1234 for example) afterwards.

Thx!

Comment: su (and most other programs that expect a password) clears the input buffer before prompting for the password, to prevent this sort of thing because it's very insecure.

Comment: Why is it insecure? Im trying to write a little script for myself and the password part is the bottleneck

Comment: If you do not want to give a password to su, use sudo and change `/etc/sudoers` so that sudo does not ask for a password.  `man visudo`

Comment: It's insecure because you're storing a password in a readable form in your script.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sudo` instead.

Modify /etc/sudoers adding this line:

`$user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`

Where $user is your username. Than you will be able to run sudo command without any password.